# LaTeX 3 / expl3 help understanding \cs:w and expansion order

Tags: expl3, expansion

I've been trying to learn the L3 programming layer while writing a simple package to set and use text "styles".

The background is that I added key--value arguments to my class that are supposed to work like this:

```latex
\documentclass[
    style/footnote       = {small,sans,FF0000},
    style/chapter-name   = uppercase, % full uppercase
]{desert}
```

The truth is that don't understand L3, even after working through most of `l3.pdf`.
Here's what I need help with:

1. I'm clearly using `\cs:w` incorrectly.
2. I haven't been able to understand the flow, particularly *when* LaTeX expands what, and where I should use `:n`, `:x`, or `:v`. (I'll add that TeX's error messages aren't exactly great.)
3. I want my macro `\txtuppertosc`, along with `\txtuppercase`, etc., to behave like switches a la `\LARGE` or `\bfseries`, for the switch `\TxtStyle` to work with those. Is there a way to do this?

**Update:** David Carlisle pointed out that I was incorrectly wrapping `:N` arguments in `{}`. The original macros are at the bottom.

#### Update code:

```latex
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\ProvidesExplPackage{txtstyles}{2022-02-02}{0.1}{Text styles}
\RequirePackage[
    dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,
    hyperref
]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{fontsize}


% build up aliases for style commands
\prop_new:N \g_txtstyle_aliases
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \g_txtstyle_aliases
{
    rm=rmfamily, roman=rmfamily,
    upcase=txtuppercase, uppercase=txtuppercase,
    mini=footnotesize, minir=footnotesizer%, ...
}

% --- MAIN MACRO FOR A SINGLE CSV:
% converts a single name, like "LARGE", \bf, or "red" to a command
\cs_new:Npn \convert_cmd:n #1
{
        \cs_if_exist_use:cTF{#1}
        {}  % option 1: a command that starts with \
        {
            % options 2 (named alias) and 3 (color)
            \prop_get:NnNTF \g_txtstyle_aliases {#1}
            {} { \color{#1} }
        }
}

%%% MAIN MACRO FOR DECLARING A STYLE:
% defines a new style as a list of commands (via \convert_cmd)
\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareTxtStyle}{m >{\SplitList{,}}m}
{
    \cs_gset:cpn{g_txtstyle_#1:} ##1
    { \tl_map_inline:Nn #2 { \convert_cmd:n{###1} } }
}

% Sets the text style (similar to \bfseries, etc.)
\NewDocumentEnvironment{TxtStyle}{m+b}
{
    \cs_if_exist_use:cTF{g_txtstyle_#1:}
    {}
    { \stylemissingerr:n{#1} }  % defined elsewhere
}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\StyleTxt}{m+m}
{ \begin{TxtStyle}{#1} #2 \end{TxtStyle} }
```

#### `main.tex`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{txtstyles}

\begin{document}

\DeclareTxtStyle{mystyle}{large,red}
\StyleTxt{mystyle}{This is some text.}

\end{document}
```

For reference, the original macros were:

```latex
% map an alias to its \command-value (e.g. roman becomes rmseries)
\cs_new:Npn \standardize_alias:n #1
{
    \prop_item:Nn \g_txtstyle_aliases {#1}
}

% converts a single name, like "LARGE", \bf, or "red" to a command
\cs_new:Npn \convert_cmd:n #1
{
    \prop_if_in:NVTF \g_txtstyle_aliases {#1}
    { \cs:w \standardize_alias:n{#1} \cs_end: }  % option 1: common name
    {
        \cs_if_exist_NTF {\cs:w #1 \cs_end:}
        { \cs:w #1 \cs_end: }  % option 2: a command name that starts with \
        { \color{#1} }  % option 3: a color, or fail
    }
}

% just gets the internal command name for a style
\cs_new:Npn \txtstyle_cmd_name:n #1
{ \cs:w g_txtstyle_#1:n \cs_end: }

% defines a new style as a list of commands (via \convert_cmd)
\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareTxtStyle}{m >{\SplitList{,}}m}
{
    \cs_set:Npn { \txtstyle_cmd_name:n{#1}  } {}
    { \tl_map_inline:Nn {#2} { \convert_cmd:n{##1} } }
}
```

Comment: `\cs:w` is just `\csname` (but you should almost never need that as expl3 gives higher level control over generating csnames such as the `c` argument type.  but I think your main error is extra braces `\cs:w {large}\cs_end:` is the undefined command with name `{large}` (includeing the braces), not `\large`

Comment: an `N` argument should be a single unbraced command token so not  `\cs_if_exist:NTF{\cs:w {#1} \cs_end:}` or `\cs_set:Npn { \txtstyle_cmd_name:n{#1} }`

Comment: in answer to your question 3 no that's essentially not possible, you can generate a command with argument from a switch eg define `\textbf` using `\bfseries` but you can not go the other way.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Is the correct usage `\cs_if_exist:NF \txtstyle_cmd_name:n{#1}`? And if `txtstyle_cmd_name` were defined with `:N`, would `\cs_if_exist:NF \txtstyle_cmd_name:N #1` be correct? It's hard to grapple with the fact that braces are used for grouping, yet also matter as TeX tokens. Removing the extra braces around each `\cs:w` did not change the error.

Comment: Also, should I be using `\tl_use:N` in `\cs:w \tl_use:N \standardize_alias:n{#1} \cs_end:`?

Comment: I think I couldn't use the `c` arg type because `\convert_cmd:n` will accept either a command, or a style name, or a color. The latter two are used to define a command to return.

Comment: the tokens allowed in a `c` argument are (exactly) the same as those allowed between `\cs:w` and `\cs_end:` and must expand to the name of a command so I do not understand your last comment at all, sorry.

Comment: `\cs_if_exist:NF \txtstyle_cmd_name:n{#1}` is syntactically correct but you have not said what you want it to do, that expands to nothing if `\txtstyle_cmd_name:n` is defined and expands to whatever is in `#1` if `\txtstyle_cmd_name:n` is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take note of the expl3 argument types. `N` and `V` arguments should take a single unbraced token. You almost never need to use `\cs:w` as that is the implementation of the `c` argument type which should be used in preference.

Here I show your central command that takes an argument and executes the command if the argument is a command name, and interprets it as a color otherwise.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \convert_cmd:n #1
{
        \cs_if_exist_use:cTF{#1}
        {}  % option 2: a command that starts with \
        { \color{#1} }  % option 3: a color, or fail
}


abc ~ {\convert_cmd:n{bfseries} abc} ~
abc ~ {\convert_cmd:n{red} abc}

\ExplSyntaxOff



\end{document}
```

In your original you had

```
  \cs_if_exist:NTF{\cs:w {#1} \cs_end:}
```

but that is passing a brace group to an `N` argument and if `#1` were `bfseries` it tests if the command with name `{bfseries}` (including the braces) exists . You intended `\cs:w #1 \cs_end:` but as above it is better to just use a `c` argument and pass in `{#1}`

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful, and I think I fixed those issues. I've copied the corrected version to the question -- mind taking a look? I know `\convert_cmd:n` and `\DeclareTxtStyle` aren't quite right still. Note that the idea is to save the "style" to a macro named `g_txtstyle_<style-name>:` , for later use by `\TxtStyle`, which uses this: `\cs_if_exist_use:cTF{g_txtstyle_#1:}`.

Comment: @DouglasMyers-Turnbull  It really makes a mess of the question and answer format it you greatly edit a question after an answer posted as the answer is addressing issues no longer in the question.

Comment: I see. I wasn't sure what the best way was, because I couldn't include the updated macro to a comment. I'll restore the original source at the bottom.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Currently, your `convert_cmd:n` immediately applies styles, whereas the intent is to *declare* a style (with `DeclareTxtStyle`) for later use (with `\TxtStyle`).